# How to tranform the following TensorFlow code to PyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensor, code-conversion

I was searching for loss functions for a GAN model and then [this one](https://github.com/imatge-upc/3D-GAN-superresolution/blob/master/model.py) came out:

```
gd_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.abs(dx_real) - tf.abs(dx_fake))) + \
              tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.abs(dy_real) - tf.abs(dy_fake))) + \
              tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.abs(dz_real) - tf.abs(dz_fake)))
```

but I would like to convert the following to PyTorch because I'm using PyTorch tensors:

```
dx_real = t_target_image[:, 1:, :, :, :] - t_target_image[:, :-1, :, :, :]
```

where `t_target_image` are tensors in TensorFlow.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch is good at sticking to pure python syntax for common matrix operations, so you can just do

```
gd_loss = ((dx_real.abs() - dx_fake.abs())**2).sum() + \
              ((dy_real.abs() - dy_fake.abs())**2).sum() + \
              ((dz_real.abs() - dz_fake.abs())**2).sum()
```

If your question is specifically about converting the tensorflow tensors to pytorch tensors you should convert to numpy first then use `torch.as_tensor` to convert to pytorch.

Comment: My problem here is about the second part `dx_real = t_target_image[:, 1:, :, :, :] - t_target_image[:, :-1, :, :, :]` . The example code I put here only gets the x-axis from a 3D TensorFlow tensor and I want know it is possible to do the same but with a 3D PyTorch tensor.

Comment: Yes, this numpy-style indexing should work for pytorch tensors too. Are you running into a specific error message?

Comment: It is not giving an error but it does not give a value either. When I try to calculate this value `torch.mean((torch.abs(dx_real)` the returned value is `tensor(nan, device='cuda:0')` so I'm supposing that this `dx_real = t_target_image[:, 1:, :, :, :] - t_target_image[:, :-1, :, :, :]` is wrong.

Comment: this is a different question entirely so I suggest you post another question with the specific problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
dx_real = real[:, :, :, 1:, :] - real[:, :, :, :-1, :]
dy_real = real[:, :, 1:, :, :] - real[:, :, :-1, :, :]
dz_real = real[:, :, :, :, 1:] - real[:, :, :, :, :-1]
dx_fake = fake[:, :, :, 1:, :] - fake[:, :, :, :-1, :]
dy_fake = fake[:, :, 1:, :, :] - fake[:, :, :-1, :, :]
dz_fake = fake[:, :, :, :, 1:] - fake[:, :, :, :, :-1]
gd_loss = torch.sum(torch.pow(torch.abs(dx_real) - torch.abs(dx_fake),2),dim=(2,3,4)) + \
          torch.sum(torch.pow(torch.abs(dy_real) - torch.abs(dy_fake),2),dim=(2,3,4)) + \
          torch.sum(torch.pow(torch.abs(dz_real) - torch.abs(dz_fake),2),dim=(2,3,4))
return torch.sum(gd_loss)`
```